# Solution to Schrödinger's equation for an electron gas in presence of an electric field by Gauge transform

Tags: electrons, electric-fields, schroedinger-equation, gauge

Schrödinger's equation for an electron gas in presence of an electric field, which is given by:

$$
\left( - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \mathbf{\nabla}^2 - q \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{r} \right) \psi(\mathbf{r},t) = \imath \hbar \frac{\partial \psi(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t} \tag{1}
$$

My teacher suggest using a Gauge transformation, for which I choose $\chi(\mathbf{r},t) = \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{r} t$ and the equation to solve is then:

$$
\frac{1}{2m} \left[ \imath \hbar \mathbf{\nabla} + q \mathbf{E} t \right]^2 \psi'(\mathbf{r},t) = \imath \hbar \frac{\partial \psi'(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t} \tag{2}
$$

with

$$
\psi'(\mathbf{r},t) = \psi(\mathbf{r},t) \exp[-\frac{\imath}{\hbar} q \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{r} t] \tag{3}
$$

Therefore, solving equation (2) we can solve $\psi(\mathbf{r},t)$ from (3). The question is, how do we solve equation (2)? I know the solution is of the form:

$$
\psi'(\mathbf{r},t) = A \exp[\imath \mathbf{k_0} \cdot \mathbf{r} + \imath g(t)] \tag{4}
$$

with

$$
g(t) = - \frac{1}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{t} \epsilon(t') dt'
$$

and where $\epsilon(t)$ is the energy of the electron:

$$
\epsilon(t) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left(\mathbf{k_0} + \frac{q \mathbf{E} }{\hbar}t \right)^2
$$

Here $\mathbf{k_0}$ stands for the initial wave vector of the electron.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the equation. It turns out it wasn't more complicated than making the supposition that the function $\psi'(\mathbf{r},t)$ accepts separation of variables. Given that the electric field is *uniform*, the Hamiltonian is independent of the coordinates, and so we make the following Ansatz:

$$
\psi'(\mathbf{r},t) = \exp[i \mathbf{k_0} \cdot \mathbf{r}] \phi(t) \tag{5}
$$

Plugging (5) into (2) we get to an ordinary first order differential equation on $\phi(t)$, which can be easily solved taking into account the *Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* (that's why we get to an integral form for the function $g(t)$ in (4)).

Let me know if you have any questions and I can edit filling the details here.